# How to change state without re-rendering in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am making an app which is calling an API repeatedly and changing state, and I have another function which is listening to an event and update some state but I want to update it without re-rendering because it causes some unwanted behaviour to chain of repeatedly API calling,

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to use - useCallback? or dividing the component into smaller components so if you update the search component it won't update other parts of the main component.

Comment: Please provide us [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we need to know how you manage your api calls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some data without triggering rerender, use `useRef()` hook for this instead of useState.

Comment: The data update process is done by API and I want to display the current value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by removing the function call depend on state.